# UWP. How to find out size of uwp-c# Windows.Storage element?

Tags: c#, windows, size, uwp, storage

How find out size of "files" or each element(foreach (var file in files)) if files list? Could be quite big.
WPF's serialization doesnt work in UWP.

```
  var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
      openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

      var files = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var fileProperties = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
    var size = fileProperties.Size;
}
```